# HP LaserJet 3052 Scanner stopped working

Tags: hp-laserjet, multi-function-printer

I'm trying to get the scanner part of an HP LaserJet 3052 working again. For some reason, it stopped working altogether. Most of the time it simply says "Waiting for PC", and others the scanner starts up like its going to work, then it goes back and forth in one side not doing anything. The firmware looks like its up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Are the drivers up to date? what does the device manger say under imaging devices? Try scanning with [IRfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) and see if it works. You should also try the scanner on another PC that way we can rule out a hardware malfunction.